# AFNetworking http basic authentication gives error "Your API key was not formatted properly"

Tags: ios, objective-c, httprequest, afnetworking, basic-authentication

Trying to use the [postmates api](https://postmates.com/developer/docs#authentication), but running into issues with authorization.

To quote their site:

> AUTHENTICATION
>
> The Postmates API requires authentication by HTTP Basic Auth headers.
>   Your API key should be included as the username. The password should
>   be left empty.
>
> The actual header that is used will be a base64-encoded string like
>   this:
>
> `Basic Y2YyZjJkNmQtYTMxNC00NGE4LWI2MDAtNTA1M2MwYWYzMTY1Og==`

I tried using AFNetworking like so

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"(my postmates key)" password:@"" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:@"https://api.postmates.com/v1/delivery_zones" parameters:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCredential:credential];
[operation setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer alloc]];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
}];

[manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

The error message I'm getting is

```
   Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.

 Success: {
        code = "invalid_authorization_header";
        kind = error;
        message = "Your API key was not formatted properly";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a credential, you might want to try:

```
[request setValue:@"Basic Y2YyZjJkNmQtYTMxNC00NGE4LWI2MDAtNTA1M2MwYWYzMTY1Og==" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```